# Beginner: Link UITabeViewCell to it's details view (UINavigationView)

Tags: ios, xcode4.2

I have UITableView which contains cells. what I would like to do once user tab into the UITableViewCell it shows a UINavigationView.

if possible i would like to this using Storyboard with interface builder, otherwise programmatically will also be OK.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to https://developer.apple.com/videos/archive/ and watch their presentation called "Introducing Interface Builder Storyboarding from WWDC 2011".

Their presentation does exactly want you want and shows you step-by-step how to do it. You need to login as an Apple developer to watch it though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear on the question, but as I read it, the architecture is not quite right (for storyboarding or otherwise).

The architecture should be:

UITabBarController --> UINavigationController -->UITableViewController -->UITableViewCell

When tapped, the cell can segue or push another "detail" view controller. It should not push an additional (or any) UINavigationController.